# Checkpoint Resuming Throwing Assertion - ARM Arch

Tags: gem5

I am trying to create and resume from a checkpoint for an ARM compiled binary (LLVM Test Suite).

1. I cross compiled the LLVM Test Suite with the following command in a Makefile:

   <sup>./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -O0 -ggdb3 -std=c99 -static $< -o $@</sup>

   (basically using the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc cross compiler version 7.4)
2. I created the checkpoints using the following command:

   <sup>./build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir=chkpt_only/  configs/example/se.py --checkpoint-dir chkpt_only/ --take-checkpoints=0,20000000000 --cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU --cmd=../../../Benchmarks/LLVM_Test_Suite/SingleSource/Benchmarks/Stanford/Towers</sup>
3. I tried to resume from the checkpoint with the following command:

   <sup>./build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir=chkpt_only/ configs/example/se.py -r 1 --checkpoint-dir chkpt_only/ --cpu-type=O3_ARM_v7a_3 --caches --cmd=../../../Benchmarks/LLVM_Test_Suite/SingleSource/Benchmarks/Stanford/Towers</sup>

The above seems to work when the `--cpu-type` is `In-order` but for any O3 CPU I get the following assertion:

> gem5.opt: build/ARM/cpu/o3/rename_map.hh:282: const PhysRegId* UnifiedRenameMap::lookup(const RegId&) const: Assertion `vecMode == Enums::Elem' failed.

Can someone please help me to understand/fix this assertion?

PS: The git commit is 2775f55447edb344d99f30273ad93fea515d7e2b

Comment: Thanks for the report. Please always give your gem5 git SHA you tested with. It would also be interesting to determine if this happens with a minimal C hello world. We might have a fix for this, I'll ping this thread when it is published.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The git commit id is 2775f55447edb344d99f30273ad93fea515d7e2b. I tried to create/resume checkpoint for the hello program already available on the gem5 repo. It still has the same assertion.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I'll try to have a look when I get some time. But do try to debug it a bit yourself as well with GDB, sometimes it is not very hard ;-)

Comment: sure, it will be of lot of help. I will try debugging it with GDB too. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: The above problem doesn't occur if the ARM binaries are compiled using the 64-bit compiler. For now, this solves the problem.

Comment: (previously on answer but got deleted) This patch might solve the issue: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/25708 mentioned at: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-371 Let me know the outcome if you manage to try it out.